# How to display an image on a UiApplication in BlackBerry?

Tags: image, blackberry, uiapplication

How to display an image on a UiApplication?

I have a code that displays a button and when clicked it goes to a `MainScreen`, but I'd like to display an image below that button. I found a way to insert a **zoomable** image but not a **static** one.

Here's my code so far:

```java
public class HelloWorldDemo extends UiApplication {
    private MainScreen _screen;
    private ButtonField _nextScreen;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         HelloWorldDemo instance = new HelloWorldDemo();
         instance.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public HelloWorldDemo() {
        EncodedImage myImg = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("k.jpg");

        ZoomScreen zoomableImg = new ZoomScreen(myImg);


         _screen = new MainScreen();
         _nextScreen = new ButtonField("Go to Next Screen",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
         _nextScreen.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
               public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) {
                  pushScreen(new NextScreen());
               }
          });
          _screen.setTitle(new LabelField("Hello World Demo",LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH));
          _screen.add(new RichTextField("Hello to the BlackBerry World!",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
          _screen.add(_nextScreen);
          pushScreen(_screen);
          pushScreen(zoomableImg);

   }

}
```

Comment: Use `BitmapField` to display an image. API Link here, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html. `myImg.getBitmap()` will return a `Bitmap` which can be used to create the `BitmapField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I'm confused about your question. But still I'm posting ans here hope it will help you.
public final class ZoomScreenDemo extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        UiApplication app = new ZoomScreenDemo();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }


    public ZoomScreenDemo()
    {
        pushScreen(new ZoomScreenDemoScreen());
    }


    public final static class ZoomScreenDemoScreen extends MainScreen
    {    
        private EncodedImage _image;   
        private ButtonField _nextScreen;

        public ZoomScreenDemoScreen()
        {           
            setTitle("Zoom Screen Demo");          

            _nextScreen = new ButtonField("Go to next screen ",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
            _nextScreen.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                     UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new DemoZoomScreen(_image));
                }
            });

            add( _nextScreen );
            _image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/building.jpg");        
            BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(_image.getBitmap(), FIELD_HCENTER | FOCUSABLE);
            add(bitmapField);            
        }       
    }    



    static class DemoZoomScreen extends ZoomScreen
    {    
        DemoZoomScreen(EncodedImage image)
        {
            super(image);
        }

        public void zoomedOutNearToFit()
        {            
            close();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..I rewrote the code from scratch using yours as example and now it's working...